# Splitting a Dataframe Column in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to drop some rows from my Pandas Dataframe `df`. It looks like this and has 180 rows and 2745 columns. I want to get rid of those rows which have a `curv_typ` of `PYC_RT` and `YCIF_RT`. I also want to get rid of the `geo\time` column. I am extracting this data from a CSV File and have to realize that `curv_typ,maturity,bonds,geo\time` and the characters below it like `PYC_RT,Y1,GBAAA,EA` are all in one column:

```
 curv_typ,maturity,bonds,geo\time  2015M06D16   2015M06D15   2015M06D11   \
0                 PYC_RT,Y1,GBAAA,EA        -0.24        -0.24        -0.24   
1               PYC_RT,Y1,GBA_AAA,EA        -0.02        -0.03        -0.10   
2                PYC_RT,Y10,GBAAA,EA         0.94         0.92         0.99   
3              PYC_RT,Y10,GBA_AAA,EA         1.67         1.70         1.60   
4                PYC_RT,Y11,GBAAA,EA         1.03         1.01         1.09
```

I decided to try and split this Column and then drop the resulting individual columns, but I am getting the error `KeyError: 'curv_typ,maturity,bonds,geo\time'` in the last line of the code `df_new = pd.DataFrame(df['curv_typ,maturity,bonds,geo\time'].str.split(',').tolist(), df[1:]).stack()`

```
import os
import urllib2
import gzip
import StringIO
import pandas as pd

baseURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file="
filename = "data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"
outFilePath = filename.split('/')[1][:-3]

response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = StringIO.StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read())

compressedFile.seek(0)

decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb') 

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())

#Now have to deal with tsv file
import csv

with open(outFilePath,'rb') as tsvin, open('ECB.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(csvout)
    for data in tsvin:
        writer.writerow(data)


csvout = 'C:\Users\Sidney\ECB.csv'
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csvout)
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Sidney\ECB.csv', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")
print df
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df['curv_typ,maturity,bonds,geo\time'].str.split(',').tolist(), df[1:]).stack()
```

**Edit**: From reptilicus's Answer I used the code below:

```
#Now have to deal with tsv file
import csv

outFilePath = filename.split('/')[1][:-3] #As in the code above, just put here for reference
csvout = 'C:\Users\Sidney\ECB.tsv'
outfile = open(csvout, "w")
with open(outFilePath, "rb") as f:
    for line in f.read():
        line.replace(",", "\t")
        outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("ECB.tsv", sep="\t", index_col=False)
```

I still get the same exact output as before.

Thank You

Comment: Just looks like you need to read it in differently. It looks like curve_type, maturity, bonds, geo\time should all have own columns. Try DataFrame.from_csv() also

Comment: @reptilicus Thank You. However, I get the same error when using `df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csvout)` instead of `pd.read_csv`. I am lost as to how to handle this.

Comment: Oh, I think its the \t in geo\time perhaps, when you read it in it might me messing up that column

Comment: Try to edit the CSV file and replace geo\time with geo_time or something perhaps?

Comment: @reptilicus Thanks! I think that might be the way to go. After making this change `geo_time` manually in the CSV File, I now get the error `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 180), indices imply (4, 179)`. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: actually looking at the data in the file, it looks like just really poorly formatted data. The first 4 cols are comma separated, and the rest are tab separated, which is dumb. I'm not sure how to fix that, perhaps use SED to replace all the commas with a \t (tab) char and then try to read it in?

Comment: tr ',' '\t' < irt_euryld_d.tsv > test.tsv

Comment: on a *nix machine, can use the `tr` command to replace those commas

Answer (score 1):

The format of that CSV is awful, there are comma and tab separated data in there.

Get rid of the commas first:

```
tr ',' '\t' < irt_euryld_d.tsv > test.tsv
```

If you can't use `tr` can just do it in python:

```
outfile = open("outfile.tsv", "w")
with open("irt_euryld_d.tsz", "rb") as f:
    for line in f.read():
        line.replace(",", "\t")
        outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

Then can load it up nicely in pandas:

```
In [9]: df = DataFrame.from_csv("test.tsv", sep="\t", index_col=False)

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
    curv_typ maturity    bonds geo\time  2015M06D17   2015M06D16   \
0     PYC_RT       Y1    GBAAA       EA        -0.23        -0.24
1     PYC_RT       Y1  GBA_AAA       EA        -0.05        -0.02
2     PYC_RT      Y10    GBAAA       EA         0.94         0.94
3     PYC_RT      Y10  GBA_AAA       EA         1.66         1.67
In [11]: df[df["curv_typ"] != "PYC_RT"]
Out[11]:
    curv_typ maturity    bonds geo\time  2015M06D17   2015M06D16   \
60   YCIF_RT       Y1    GBAAA       EA        -0.22        -0.23
61   YCIF_RT       Y1  GBA_AAA       EA         0.04         0.08
62   YCIF_RT      Y10    GBAAA       EA         2.00         1.97
```

Comment: Thank You. But is there a way to replace the commas with tabs in a script as I need to automate the whole process?

Comment: Thank You. I used the code you provided and only made changes to the names of the files, but I still get the Output in the exact same format as before. I've edited the question to show the code that I used. Do you know why this might be?